# Spring | JPA | Choose correct CascadeType annotation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, annotations, cascade

Inside a Spring Boot server backend I need to create a bidirectional association between two entities (User/Match). A user could have many matches and a match always contains two users. The problem is that I do not find the correct cascade annotation for the association properties.

The issue is that there is no update of the user's match list, when I call the likeUser method in the MatchService. I create a new match object and set the back reference from user to match (adding the match to its list of matches) in the user-setter method of match and save the match afterwards. But the manipulation of the users match list wont be saved in the database.

Does anyone know the correct way of solving this problem?

Here is a short extract of my code:

```
@Entity(name =  "User_")
public class User { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;    

    private String username;    

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;    

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Match.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Match> matches;    

    public void addMatch(Match match) {
        matches.add(match);
    }
}   

@Entity(name = "Match_")
public class Match {    


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;    

    /**
     * User 1 is always the user who likes the other person first
     */
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    private User user1; 

    /**
     * User 2 is the user who has to confirm the match
     */
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    private User user2; 

    public void setUser1(User user1) {
        this.user1 = user1;
        user1.addMatch(this);
    }   

    public void setUser2(User user2) {
        this.user2 = user2;
        user2.addMatch(this);
    }   

    public void setUsers(User user1, User user2) {
        this.setUser1(user1);
        this.setUser2(user2);
    }
}
@Service
public class MatchService {
    public void addMatch(Match match) {
        matchRepository.save(match);
    }
    /**
     * Method that is called if one user likes another.
     *
     * @param likedUser - the user who has been liked by initialUser
     * @return - the match object that has either been created or was already existing
     */
    public Match likeUser(User likedUser) {
        User initialUser = userService.getCurrentUser();
        //check if likedUser has already like initialUser
        for (Match match : likedUser.getMatches()) {
            if (match.getUser2().equals(initialUser)) {
                match.confirm();
                return match; // its a match
            }
        }
        Match unconfirmedMatch = new Match();
        unconfirmedMatch.setUsers(initialUser, likedUser);
        addMatch(unconfirmedMatch);
        return unconfirmedMatch;
    }
}
```

Comment: "users match list wont be saved in the database". Do you mean the user1 and user2 columns in the database are empty? How are your User and Match classes mapped?

Comment: You shouldn't need any cascading at all. Are you sure `likedUser` and `initialUser` are not in a detached state? Is there a transaction around `likeUser`? The lack of `@Transactional` suggests there isn't

Comment: @crizzis I think this is the problem. I didn't know that I need a '@Transactional annotation. So likeUser are in a detached state. What is the best practice to solve this problem? Do I have to write the '@Transactional annotation on each method that works with JPA entities? Or is it better to have an EntityManager object for attaching objects?

Comment: If you annotate `likeUser` with `@Transactional`, `initialUser` will not become detached immediately after the call to `getCurrentUser`. However, `likedUser` will still be detached. Where does `likedUser` come from? You should fetch it from inside the `likeUser` method

Comment: likedUser comes from my RestController. If you press "like" on a user at the frontend, the likedUser is send as a json object to the controller. The controller then calls the matchService.likeUser(likedUser) method. This method in the service layer gets the currentUser (initialUser) from the securtiyContext from the userService. Its checks if likedUser has already liked the initialUser. Let's say the likedUser has not reliked the initialUser. Then a new match object is created. The setter-method setUsers(initialUser, likedUser) added the new match to the match list of the respective user.

Comment: Afterwards the new created match is saved inside the persistence layer (via a CrudRepository interface) by calling the matchSerice.addMatch(unconfirmedMatch) method. 
The Problem is: When I check the match list of the users, it is still empty, because only the match object is refreshed in the persistence layer.